# how long was a mongo instance running

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have MongoDb running on the machine on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

I there a way to find for how long was it running without restarts without accessing mongo log files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In mongo shell

```
db.serverStatus().uptime
```

This will print the uptime with seconds

And you can use the following:

```
// minutes
db.serverStatus().uptime / 60

// hours
db.serverStatus().uptime / 3600

// days
db.serverStatus().uptime / 86400
```

A more convenient method:

```
mongo --quiet --eval "db.serverStatus().uptime"
```

Comment: Oh, last command should be executed in normal shell(like bash), not in `mongo shell`. It's more convenient because you don't have to enter into `mongo shell`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, try:

```
ps -ef
```

it works for me.
You get the STIME (start time) field for all processes, including mongodb.

I get something like

```
my_user_id 12853     1  0 Nov13 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./bin/start_mongodb_mongod.sh
```

Comment: not much, the fields I get are:
UID   PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
which means : user_ID,process ID, process Parent ID, i dunno, start time, terminal, time (but dunno what it exactly represents), and the command that was actually launched